# UNIQUE constraint failed Error when save new obj in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have this model:

```
#models.py
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curriculum, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    enrolment_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
    payed_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    is_complete_paid = models.BooleanField(null=True,blank=True,default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("student", "curriculum"),)
```

and when I want to create new enrollment in my `views.py` with this codes:

```
new_enrollment = Enrollment.objects.create(student_id=request.user.id,curriculum_id=curriculum_id)
```

I got this error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: lms_enrollment.student_id,
>   lms_enrollment.curriculum_id

**Why this error happened?** Is it possible to explain the cause of this error and introduce some documentations about that?

Comment: you already have a Enrollment in your database with the same student, curriculum

Comment: Just want to mention that `unique_together` is deprecated (but that's probably not what your problem is). Here's a link to the new way to do the same thing, the [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    curriculum = models.ForeignKey(Curriculum, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    payed_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("student", "curriculum"),)
```

Meta.unique_together means that both of the fields can't be same for more than 1 item in the database

```
Enrollment.objects.create(student=student1, curriculum=curriculum1, payed_amount=100)
Enrollment.objects.create(student=student2, curriculum=curriculum1, payed_amount=200)
#Only curriculum is the same
Enrollment.objects.create(student=student1, curriculum=curriculum2, payed_amount=300)
#Only student is the same
Enrollment.objects.create(student=student1, curriculum=curriculum1, payed_amount=400)
#Both student and curriculum is the same with the first object,
hence it raises UNIQUE constraint failed error
```